# How to fix wrong parenthesis direction in Hebrew text in Google Chrome?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, mediawiki, hebrew

A few months ago, a weird behavior emerged whenever I open the Hebrew Wikipedia page on my Mac using Chrome. The parenthesis and brackets are reversed.

Here's an example from [https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/ויקיפדיה](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%95%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%A4%D7%93%D7%99%D7%94):

[image: Image of Hebrew text with wrongly oriented brackets]

This is highly annoying and made me unhappy reading through Wikipedia.
I thought it might be an LTR issue, but Farsi and Arabic look just fine!

Hebrew text displays fine on my phone.

I was wondering if anyone else might have seen this. Is this an issue in Chrome, or might it be something specific to Wikipedia or MediaWiki?

Comment: Do you have a link to the page showing the problem?

Comment: A link would be useful. This could be an error with Wikipedia itself rather than with your browser. Does this happen with other browsers than Chrome?

Comment: thanks @DavidPostill for embedding the image. harrymc - no, i've tested on my phone, on my safari, on a friend iphone using chrome. none of them show this problem.

Comment: It definitely is an LTR issue (the Unicode Bidirectional Algorithm trying to deal with the mix of LTR and RTL text, and making the wrong choice for the braces). You might want to leave a note on the talk page of the affected template.

Comment: @Tgr it's everywhere. all of wikipedia. content as well as non-content (like the brackets around edit command).

Comment: What happens if you copy the text to a non-bidi-aware interface (like a basic text editor, or command line)?

Comment: What's the code point of the braces? You can check in something like https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm .

Comment: @Tgr in other text editors (sublime, google sheets and iterm) the parenthesis behaviour is as expected (i.e., they surround the text properly). when inspecting the page in chrome the text also appears just fine. the code points are the expected left Parenthesis and right parenthesis.

Comment: I mean, do the parentheses get switched of flipped? If you copy the closing parenthesis that shows up on the left side into some code point checker, will it be identified as an opening or closing parenthesis?

Comment: Also please do link to pages where you see this problem.

Comment: @Tgr they are not flipped, they are the same parenthesis used in other popular Hebrew sites like ynet.co.il. it will recognize them as Left and Right parenthesis (which is actually the opposite that you would expect from Hebrew) but it looks like that's the correct behaviour as the same text shows up just fine in other editors.

Comment: Does this only happen when the namespace has Latin characters?

Answer (score 0):

This is how the linked article looks to me in Chrome 81 (on Ubuntu):
[image]

The parens are flipped: the one on the left is [U+0029 RIGHT PARENTHESIS](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0029/index.htm), the one on the right is [U+0028 LEFT PARENTHESIS](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0028/index.htm). This is [expected behavior](https://unicode.org/reports/tr9/#L4) for the Unicode bidirectional text algoritghm: certain characters such as those that come in open/close pairs are displayed in a horizontally mirrored form when they are in an RTL context.

The HTML code does not contain anything bidi-related so this is definitely a browser issue.